# Cookie based authorization before calling controllers method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, cookies

Recently I came accross this issue. Let's say that I want to give different authorizations to different methods within my controller. I would like to do this using the cookie that was send with the request and to do that I would like to use annotations. I tried to figure out how force @PreAuthorize annotation to work but I am missing something here.

Does anyone know if it's possible scenario (pseudo-code)

```
@Controller
class myController
{
    @SomeAuthorizationAnnotation
    @RequestMapping("/")
    void doSth()
    {
        //something is done after authorization
    }
}
```

And now i'd like to write my custom method which grants me access to http request sent to this controller where i could let's say write something like

```
HttpServletRequest ht = ....

Optional<Cookie> cookie = getCookie(ht.getCookies(), AUTH_TOKEN);
if (cookie.isPresent()) {
    //grant authorization for the method call
}
```

I hope that this is somewhat understandable.

P.S I don't want to bind filters or sth to url's, i want to bind it to methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In way to secure your methods you can use @Secured or @PreAuthorize annotations but also you should declare it `<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />`
See also [method security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-method-security)

Comment: Tell me please. In your case if I send request through webserver I get exception. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Well, my solution to this problem was by simply using Authentication Providers within Spring Security and implement interface of UserDetailsService to match my demands according to this project. So then my sessions are automatically handled without necessity for handling Cookies myself. And of course, annotations work.